# How do i create and fill a file in the directory the User choose with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE on Android 9-11

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions

I try to make an Export Function for my App, that can export(and later Import) data to a txt-file in the shared storage. I use the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to choose a Folder and get "resultdata: Intent?" back.

For explanation in the Downloads-folder/Documents-Folder there is a "myApp"-folder. The user gave permission for that folder. So i get an Intent? with the path to this place back

How can i use that to create a "Spells.txt" in said folder without ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT

Edit: Thanks to blackapps, I've found DocumentFile, which helped create and fill the File. Here are the relevant parts of my Code so far:

```
        lateinit var permissedFolder: Intent
```

in onCreate

```
        permissiontest_btn_Choose_Permission.setOnClickListener(){chooseFolder()}
        permissiontest_btn_createFile.setOnClickListener(){createFile()}
```

```
    fun chooseFolder(){
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE).apply {
    }
    startActivityForResult(intent, 100)
}
```

```
        
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, resultData: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultData)
        if(requestCode==100 && resultCode== RESULT_OK){
            if (resultData != null) {
                permissedFolder = resultData
            }
```

```
fun createFile() {

    if(permissedFolder.data != null) {
        val folderUri:Uri = permissedFolder.data!!
        val enabledDirectory:DocumentFile= DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, folderUri)!!

        val spellsExportDF =enabledDirectory.createFile(".txt","Spells.txt")
        val spellsExportURI = spellsExportDF?.uri

        if(spellsExportURI != null) {
            val fileOutputStream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(spellsExportURI)
            //FileOutputStream(spellsExportURI, true)
            fileOutputStream.use { fileout ->
                fileout?.writer(Charsets.UTF_8)?.use {
                    it.write(test)

                    it.flush()
                    it.close()
                }
            }
            val readfile = spellsExportDF.canRead()
            val writefile =spellsExportDF.canWrite()
            Toast.makeText(this, "can Read: $readfile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            Toast.makeText(this, "can Write: $writefile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
```

Comment: Creating a file in a directory choosed by the user using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE is a basic SAF action. It looks that you did not google that example. DocumentFile.createFile().

Comment: Thanks. Been googling for three days just for this problem and haven't found anything helpful. Probably used the wrong keywords.
Can i just put that DocumentFile into shared preferences, to keep it usable across the different Activities and after a Reboot of the device?

Comment: We can conclude that you did not google for DocumentFile.createFile(). Further you have no DocumentFile yet so what is it that you wanna put in shared preferences? Its time you post some code.

Comment: Oh i wouldn't say I have no DocumentFile and i have googled after reading your comment. I just didn't find the parts i was looking for and since i have someone, that knows about it, i thought why not ask instead getting stuck for another three days before asking into the Net

Comment: Well you found all.. great.. wel done. Just some small hints did it!